# Search into non symetrical multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have found a lot of question and some great answers in order to search into an array with PHP. But everytime, the script answered too perfectly to the quesiton, and not globaly OR all arrays are symetricals.

My Array can look like this:

```
$data = [
    'steve' => [
        'id'     => [
            '#text' => 1,
        ],
        'pseudo' => [
            '#text' => 'LOL'
        ],
    ],
    'albert' => [
        'id'     => [
            '#text' => 2,
        ],
        'pseudo' => [
            '#text' => 'KILLER'
        ],
    ],
    'john' => [
        'id'     => [
            '#text' => 3,
        ],
        'pseudo' => [
            '#text' => 'NOOBS'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Which mean that my Array can look beautifully symetrically generated, or completely messy and with random subarray.

My aim is to search inside and found the PSEUDO of AN ID. And unfortunately, I can't change the webservice which give me this result.

I had tried with array_column or array_search, but the only thing I had successfully returned is if it founds something, or not. But can't identify it. And my script was very slow.

Something like :

```
search($array, 2); //which return KILLER
```

or more optionable maybe?

My Array can have a lot of IDs (100+). So I'm trying to found something optimize. :/

Comment: You need recursive search. Show your code

Comment: `killer`? There's no such data in provided array.

Comment: Please use *copyable* input data. For example produced with [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/var_export). `print_r` produces readable outputs, but parsing it back to actually usable data is simply a pain.

Comment: I had updated the ARRAY, wront copy/paste...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a million ways to do this, but ultimately you'll need some recursive approach that's able to filter on the value and the path to that value. For this, the following would be one of those million ways.

It uses the predefined iterators:

- [CallbackFilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php)
- [RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)
- [RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php)

in combination with a custom `PathAsKeyDecorator` iterator.

[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/fmrAk)

---

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

final class PathAsKeyDecorator implements \Iterator
{
    private RecursiveIteratorIterator $inner;

    public function __construct(RecursiveIteratorIterator $inner)
    {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->inner->current();
    }

    public function next(): void
    {
        $this->inner->next();
    }

    public function key()
    {
        $path = [];
        for ($i = 0, $depth = $this->inner->getDepth(); $i <= $depth; $i++) {
            $path[] = $this->inner->getSubIterator($i)->key();
        }

        return $path;
    }

    public function valid(): bool
    {
        return $this->inner->valid();
    }

    public function rewind(): void
    {
        $this->inner->rewind();
    }
}

$input = [
    'steve'  => [
        'id' => [
            '#text' => 1,
        ],
    ],
    'albert' => [
        'id' => [
            '#text' => 2,
        ],
    ],
    'john'   => [
        'profil' => [
            'id' => [
                '#text' => 3,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

// this is the filter function that should be customized given your requirements
// or create a factory function which produces these types of filter functions
$filter = static function ($current, array $path): bool {
    // with help from the PathAsKeyDecorator
    // we can decide on the path to the current value
    return ['id', '#text'] === array_slice($path, -2)
        // and the current value
        && 2 === $current;
};


// configure the iterator
$it = new CallbackFilterIterator(
    new PathAsKeyDecorator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($input))),
    $filter,
);

// traverse the iterator
foreach ($it as $path => $val) {
    print_r([
        'path' => $path,
        'val'  => $val
    ]);
}
```

---

An alternative approach could be one with *simple* functions, like:

[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/0bj9M)

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function iterateWithPath(iterable $input, array $path = []): iterable {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $pathToHere = [...$path, $key];

        is_iterable($value)
            ? yield from iterateWithPath($value, $pathToHere)
            : yield $pathToHere => $value;
    }
}

function filterIterable(iterable $it, callable $filter): iterable {
    foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
        if ($filter($value, $key)) {
            yield $key => $value;
        }
    }
}

$input = [
    'steve'  => [
        'id' => [
            '#text' => 1,
        ],
    ],
    'albert' => [
        'id' => [
            '#text' => 2,
        ],
    ],
    'john'   => [
        'profil' => [
            'id' => [
                '#text' => 3,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$it = filterIterable(iterateWithPath($input), static function ($current, array $path): bool {
    return ['id', '#text'] === array_slice($path, -2)
        && 2 === $current;
});

foreach ($it as $path => $val) {
    print_r([
        'path' => $path,
        'val' => $val
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I had updated the original array. Wrong copy/paste...
I'm trying to understand your code for now.

Comment: @OverSu If you have questions, just ask. :)

Comment: Seems that I had a LOT of gap between what I learn (few years ago...) and now. So I will just learn all function/var/method you used. But I will have questions ;)

Comment: Damn, I have just learn a lot about ITERATOR and declare(strict_types=1). No question for now, I will check and test your script. :o

Comment: I had tested it. That's pretty fetch all requierment. But I have this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'RecursiveIteratorIterator' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /in/fmrAk on line 6

Process exited with code 255.

Comment: @OverSu That's a version 7.4 issue. It enable typed properties, which I'm using here: `private RecursiveIteratorIterator $inner;`. If you can't change your php version, simply remove the type hint, like: `private $inner;`. Further reading (for example): https://stitcher.io/blog/typed-properties-in-php-74

Comment: @OverSu I added a *functional* approach as an alternative, just to show that there really are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: That's pretty impresive. :o

Comment: @OverSu If you think this answer helped you and might be helpful to others, you might consider accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

complete edit cause of structure change of the array. the json_encode is used for changing the array to a string. Only does its job when there is in every array slice an id and an pseudo.

```
$data = [
    'steve' => [
        'id'     => [
            '#text' => 1,
        ],
        'pseudo' => [
            '#text' => 'LOL'
        ],
    ],
    'albert' => [
        'id'     => [
            '#text' => 2,
        ],
        'pseudo' => [
            '#text' => 'KILLER'
        ],
    ],
    'john' => [
        'id'     => [
            '#text' => 3,
        ],
        'pseudo' => [
            '#text' => 'NOOBS'
        ],
    ],
];


$data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
preg_match_all('~"id":{"#text":([^{]*)}~i', $data, $ids);
preg_match_all('~"pseudo":{"#text":"([^{]*)"}~i', $data, $pseudos);

$lnCounter = 0;
$laResult  = array();
foreach($ids[1] as $lnId) {
    $laResult[$lnId] = $pseudos[1][$lnCounter];
    $lnCounter++;
}

echo $laResult[2];
```

results in KILLER

Comment: Seems to be working. I had barely tested it and do the job. But if I can avoid JSON, I would like to. Because the original format is XML, which is converted into ARRAY and send via WebService. If I had to reconvert it again into JSON, well...

Comment: @OverSu i changed the code, still using json_encode as it is an simple way, changing an array to a string

Comment: I'm gonna check that tomorrow morning. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Seems to be working. Just added JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag to keep the INT format.